# Webpage Display on Brackets

Tags: html, css, adobe-brackets

I'm using the code editor Brackets to design a webpage. The page files are in HTML. I would like to send those files to a different computer to allow the user of that computer to view the webpage from the HTML files. However, even when I open the HTML files on Chrome on my computer, not opening it with Brackets, none of the CSS styling or images - basically, anything linked to the HTML page that is not HTML itself - appears. Dreamweaver, by contrast, displays webpages correctly when the HTML files are opened on their own.

How can I get the webpages to display correctly, and how can I send these webpages to a different computer so the person on that computer can open them correctly?

Comment: depends on the way your CSS is referenced - if relative it should work, if absolute it'll fail without a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

First, check that your css and images are referenced via relative path

[Absolute vs Relative](http://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/)

If you send a folder containing your HTML files, CSS files and images to another computer, it will be possible to open it in chrome and see the results.

Be sure to not have any reference - path - link to a local file. Everything you need should be in the folder you send or a online URL.

If it is still not working - please provide us more details about your project folder and your code

Comment: Everything is referenced via relative path, that is, all of the hrefs lead to files within the project folder. The links to the CSS are coded as: <link href="/CSS/pgconstruction.css" rel="stylesheet"/>. Exactly what would you like to know about the folder and code?

Comment: I wanted to know the architecture of the folder and the head code containing all the reference. Is there an error in the browser console on the other computer ?